# Enumeration that starts with "in the"

Tags: prepositions, lists, parallelism, repetition

What is grammatically correct?

> I participated in the math club, in the cycling club and in the computer game design club.

or

> I participated in the math club, the cycling club and the computer game design club.

or more formal. If you write an enumeration that starts with *in the*, do you have to repeat the words *in the* each time?

Comment: Neither is particularly more or less formal. Nor would it make much difference if you elided *"the"* after the first one. Except to make it even more obvious you didn't capitalise the math club. Do you hold mathematicians in less regard than cyclists and game designers?

Comment: It was just a minimal example (with some copy-paste work :s). thank you for your quick response.

Comment: It was just a throwaway good-natured dig (I thought it best to lighten the tone in case [Peter Shor](http://english.stackexchange.com/users/5754/peter-shor) felt slighted! :)

Comment: Pity about the commas.

Comment: You could also write _I was {active in / a member of [CHOOSE ONE]} the math, cycling, and computer-game-design clubs_. Eliminate verbosity!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the second sentence. I also insist on the so-called Oxford comma (after "club"), but some people feel otherwise.

Why not the first sentence? The first example uses the rhetorical device [anaphora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_%28rhetoric%29), and so is, strictly speaking, more formal. But the mundaneness of the sentence undercuts the effect of the device, so the repetition becomes, I think, [pleonastic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleonasm).